# XBMC PVR Add-on development documentation

Tags: documentation, add-on, xbmc

I'm currently working on a PVR backend and frontend for XBMC and I was wondering where in the world to get started? From what I have been able to learn from the addon development wiki, there seems to be a great deal of difference between "normal" addons and pvr addons. Where is the documentation for the PVR API located? Are PVR add-ons written in python? C? C++? Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

While unfortunately there is no real documentation at this time (November 11, 2013). However, opdenkamp over at the XBMC forums was kind enough to point me over to an example PVR addon on github:
https://github.com/opdenkamp/xbmc-pvr-addons/tree/master/addons/pvr.demo

and the header code for the PVR part of XBMC:
https://github.com/opdenkamp/xbmc-pvr-addons/blob/master/xbmc/xbmc_pvr_dll.h

I hope this was helpful. I will try to update this answer when I know more.

Comment: Did you forget to update the answer ?

Comment: Nope. I haven't found any more info.